# How do you print only the first solution of backtracking?

Tags: common-lisp, backtracking

I am working on the N-queens problem using backtracking in Lisp. So far, my code prints all possible solutions for n>=4. However, I wish to print only the first solution for any value of n.

```
(defun backtracksearch (row n)
// (if () *I probably need a line here to stop once the first solution is found*
(if (< row n)
  (loop for j below n
      do (when (is-safe row j n)
              (setf (aref *chessboard* row j) 'board)
              (backtracksearch (+ 1 row) n)
              (setf (aref *chessboard* row j) 'nil)))
(print-solution n)))
```

I have tried to use the same implementation/logic as that in the C++ solution of backtracking n-queens. 
Any advice on the possible way forward would be helpful.

Comment: Why is it tagged `c++`? Tag it as `lisp` instead.

Comment: "the C++ solution of backtracking n-queens" is only known to you. If you want to tell us about it, provide a reference; otherwise, don't mention it.

Answer (score 3):

#### Some feedback on your code:

- It is badly formatted, indent as follows:

  ```lisp
  (defun backtracksearch (row n)
    (if (< row n)
        (loop for j below n
              do (when (is-safe row j n)
                   (setf (aref *chessboard* row j) 'board)
                   (backtracksearch (+ 1 row) n)
                   (setf (aref *chessboard* row j) 'nil)))
        (print-solution n)))
  ```
- `//` are comments in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), use `;` instead
- `(dotimes (j n) (when ...))` would be sufficient.

#### Some questions to help you find a solution:

- What happens when there is no `j` satisfying `is-safe`?
- In particular, what is the return value of `backstracksearch`?
- What is the return value when you find a solution?
- How could you determine if a recursive call to `backtracksearch` found a solution?
- Could you use this information to avoid computing other solutions?